# Append a record's field value with a string in MS Access SQL

Tags: microsoft-access, sql

I would like to run a query that updates a field's value with whatever is already there but with an "n" appended in the end. 
For example say there's a field called `AccountNumber` and for a certain record `AccountNumber = "IP1234"`, I want it to be updated to `"IP1234n"`.

I imagine the query to be something like

```
UPDATE (Accounts.AccountNumber) = ([Accounts.AccountNumber] & "n") WHERE Accounts.AppendNumber = TRUE;
```

but with the correct syntax.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Update Accounts set AccountNumber=AccountNumber+'n' 
where Accounts.AppendNumber = TRUE;
```